# concept to check existence of function in class (problem in GCC?)

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to detect if a function (`operator()` in my case) is present in a class, regardless of its signature or whether it would be possible to get a pointer to it (may be impossible without additional info because it is templated or overloaded). The following code using a concept compiles on MSVC and clang, but not GCC (see godbolt link below for error messages). Is this supposed to work and is GCC not conformant, or is this not supposed to work and are MSVC and clang too lenient? It is interesting to note GCC fails not only for the overloaded and templated `operator()`s, but also for the simple functor.

Note also that while the example code uses variations on unary functions taking an `int`, I'd like the concept to work regardless of function signature (and its does for MSVC and clang).

Try here for [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/s8frGrbG9), [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/cesf13d5G) and [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/G75Ef69nY).

Context is making [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272935/invocable-traits-v5) work, it does now on MSVC and clang, but not GCC.

```
template <typename C>
concept HasCallOperator = requires(C t)
{
    t.operator();
};

struct functor
{
    int operator()(int in_)
    { return 1; }
};

struct functorOverloaded
{
    int operator()(const int& in_)
    { return 1; }
    int operator()(int&& in_)
    { return 1; }
};

struct functorTemplated
{
    template <typename... T>
    int operator()(const T&... in_)
    { return 1; }
};

template<HasCallOperator T>
struct B {};


int main()
{
    B<functor> a;
    B<functorOverloaded> b;
    B<functorTemplated> c;
}
```

Comment: `template <typename C>
concept HasCallOperator = requires(C t)
{ t.operator()(std::declval<int>()); };`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo - `requires(C c, int i) { c(i); }`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yeah, that's even nicer!

Comment: @TedLyngmo: thanks, but thats not what i'm looking for, it should (and does) work regardless of function signature on MSVC and clang, its just existence of the function itself. I have clarified my question

Comment: With variation `&C::operator()`, clang is too permissive [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7z5Edbs1).

Comment: Not sure you might check for existence with overload/template version...

Comment: @Jarod42: what do you mean with "you might check for existence with overload/template version"?

Comment: I think `functorOverloaded` and `functorTemplated` are/should be problematic.

Comment: @DiederickC.Niehorster: "*regardless of its signature*" How do you *use* a function "regardless of its signature"? You can't get a pointer to any function; you can only get a pointer to one with a particular signature. So what's the point of asking if a function "exists" without a signature? Remember: constraints exist to protect a particular usage of a type. Until you know the signature, you cannot use that function. So until you have a signature, there is no need for a constraint.

Comment: @NicolBolas: indeed the next step is to deduce the function signature for it to be of any use. I was trying to provide fine-grained diagnostics. If there is only one ´operator()`, then its easy to deduce its signature. If overloaded or templated, then more info (argument types) is needed. I want to distinguish the latter case from the case where `operator()` signature deduction fails because there is no `operator()`.

Comment: @DiederickC.Niehorster: You should always require argument types.

Comment: @NicolBolas: for all use cases? The [`invocable_traits`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272935/invocable-traits-v5) library i wrote originally started to solve the problem that I had a user-provided callable, and i needed to know what its input arguments and return type are. Since that is in the callable definition, a bit of template programming could pull them out (if not overloaded or templated). That use doesn't require the user to specify argument types (if i understand your point correctly)?

Comment: @DiederickC.Niehorster: "*for all use cases?*" Yes. Better to have a simple rule (provide the signature) than a complicated rule (you have to provide a signature when doing X or Y, but not Z). Until reflection exists in C++, determining the kinds of things your traits library is trying to do just isn't feasible outside of one specific case.

Comment: @NicolBolas That makes sense. What i wrote now works for me for my use case, but i agree its inconsistent and incomplete. I also am waiting for reflection, that'll make this job easier and more correct/complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the way to check a concept is just to `static_assert` (not to try to instantiate a constrained class template).

```cpp
static_assert(HasCallOperator<functor>);
static_assert(HasCallOperator<functorOverloaded>);
static_assert(HasCallOperator<functorTemplated>);
```

Second, you can't write `t.operator()` for the same reason that you can't write `f.fun` for any other non-static member function: if you do class member access, it *must* end with invocation. So this is simply a clang/msvc bug that it allows any of this.

And then `&C::operator()` will not work if the call operator is overloaded or a function template (or both).

Which really calls into question the whole point of this, since without reflection we're highly limited in the kinds of answers we can give to these questions. You can really only address the simple case of non-overloaded, non-template call operator.

---

Nevertheless, there is an approach that works here. The trick is the same problem we have in our present case: `&C::operator()` doesn't work if `operator()` is overloaded.

So what we do instead is construct a case where `&C::operator()` *would* be overloaded *if* there were one, and invert the check. That is:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Fake { void operator()(); };
template <typename T> struct Tester : T, Fake { };

template <typename C>
concept HasCallOperator = std::is_class_v<C> and not requires(Tester<C> t)
{
    &Tester<C>::operator();
};
```

`HasCallOperator<C>` doesn't check `C`, it checks a type that inherits from both `C` and a type that has a non-overloaded non-template call operator. If `&Tester<C>::operator()` is a valid expression, that means it refer to `&Fake::operator()`, which means that `C` did not have one. If `C` had a call operator (whether it's overloaded or a template or both or neither), then `&Tester<C>::operator()` would be ambiguous.

The `is_class_v` check is there to ensure that stuff like `HasCallOperator<int>` is `false` rather than ill-formed.

Note that this won't work on `final` classes.